# Alt and title fields are missing in image upload on wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, alt

Recently i have noticed that when i'm trying to upload images to some post or page in WordPress, all the fields of the title, alt, description, URL, image size.... are missing...

the site is: WWW.lotem.net if its help.

any ideas how it could happened and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: do you fill them in when you have uploaded them? if you did then some plugin or theme file is altering your images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happened *recently*, it's probably caused by a new plugin or theme you installed.

If that's the case, disable the plugin or swap the theme and see if the problem persists.

If it does persist, do a full troubleshooting:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list

Comment: so I've changed the theme and the problem was fixed.
the question is, where in the theme i need to look the problem that cause this bug?
function.php?
header?

this theme is child theme of twentyten...